# Non-standard "numbers" for figure environments

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing, numbering

I have ten figures in my article. Is it possible to set arbitrary names for some of these figures? For example, I need to "number" them as Figure a1, Figure a2, Figure b1, Figure b2,  Figure 1, Figure 2, ...

Comment: Well, the easiest way is (or seems to be) to redefine the `\thefigure` for this, depending on the desired format, but the more important question: Why do you have/want such a 'weird' numbering scheme?

Comment: Do you want to reference them? Are you using any packages for setting your figure `\caption`s (like [`caption`](//ctan.org/pkg/caption))? What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: @Werner Yes, I want to reference them. My document class is article and I use `\caption` package.

Comment: Off-topic comment: You have many questions with answers that are not accepted by you -- please go back to your question list and accept the answer(s) (No, I am not one of the users that answered so far)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I know this is unusual numbering scheme, but my teacher has asked me.

Comment: @FahimB: I am a teacher as well and I would never ask such a scheme from my students to use it in a document

Comment: @FahimB: Are you using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: If you're using `caption` package, I suggest to use a special `label format` or changing `\p@figure`, or the `subcaption` package

Comment: @Werner Yes I am using `hyperref`.

Comment: You have asked lots of questions but many do not have answers and of those that do you have often accepted any. You will have better luck if you give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), with your questions.  A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. A MWE often clarifies what you want and it makes it much easier for people to hep you -- and so much more likely that some one will help you -- because they have working code to start from. It would also help to accept more:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below I define `\setfignumprefix{<fnpf>}` that does two things:

1. Updates the macro `\fignumprefix`; and
2. Resets the `figure` counter.

The `figure` counter representation will always include `\fignumprefix` as the prefix, allowing you to update that throughout your document as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{topnumber}{4}% Just for this example
\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}% Just for this example

\newcommand{\fignumprefix}{}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\fignumprefix\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\theHfigure}{figure.\thefigure}
\newcommand{\setfignumprefix}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\fignumprefix}{#1}% Update figure counter prefix
  \setcounter{figure}{0}% Reset figure counter
}

\begin{document}

See Figures~\ref{fig:first} and~\ref{fig:second}.
After that, review Figures~\ref{fig:third} and~\ref{fig:last}.

\setfignumprefix{a}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{First figure}\label{fig:first}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Second figure}\label{fig:second}
\end{figure}

\setfignumprefix{b}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Third figure}\label{fig:third}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Last figure}\label{fig:last}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionType{figureA}[Figure]
\def\thefigureA{a\arabic{figureA}}
\DeclareCaptionType{figureB}[Figure]
\def\thefigureB{b\arabic{figureB}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figureA}[ht!]
\centering
\fbox{FIGURE}
\caption{Caption}
\label{figa:example}
\end{figureA}
See Figure~\ref{figa:example}.

\begin{figureB}[ht!]
\centering
\fbox{FIGURE}
\caption{Caption}
\label{figb:example}
\end{figureB}
See Figure~\ref{figb:example}.

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\fbox{FIGURE}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
See Figure~\ref{fig:example}.
\end{document}
```

[image]